# C# WPF error: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Failed to create a 'RequestNavigate' from the text 'Hyperlink_RequestNavigate'.'

Tags: c#, html, wpf, hyperlink, screen-scraping

I need to create an WPF app in which I'm showing text that is scraped from a site. In every new day, the text is changed. Nevertheless, the problem is that this text contains hyperlinks, and I need to scrape them also. In this sense, I am scraping the innerHtml and modifying to be readable to XAML.

Suppose I am scraping this HTML:

```xml
<p>Click <a href="google.com"> here </a> !!</p>
```

I modify this to be readable to XAML like this:

```xml
<TextBlock> Click <Hyperlink RequestNavigate=\"Hyperlink_RequestNavigate\" NavigateUri='https://www.google.com/'> here </Hyperlink> !!! </TextBlock>
```

How am I doing this?

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var str = " Click <Hyperlink RequestNavigate=\"Hyperlink_RequestNavigate\" NavigateUri='https://www.google.com/'> here </Hyperlink> !!! ";
        grid.Children.Add(CreateTextBlock(str));
    }

    public TextBlock CreateTextBlock(string inlines)
    {
        var xaml = "<TextBlock xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">"
            + inlines + "</TextBlock>";
        return XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as TextBlock;
    }

    public void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri) { UseShellExecute = true });
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

All good until now, but the error above comes in:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Failed to create a
> 'RequestNavigate' from the text 'Hyperlink_RequestNavigate'.'
> ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its
> signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you show us `Hyperlink_RequestNavigate`? On a side note, it would be easier to just embed a [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf) and loading the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `XamlReader.Parse` method doesn't support event handlers but you could simply remove `RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate"` from the XAML being parsed and handle the `RequestNavigate` event for all hyperlinks by attaching an event handler for the routed event to the `Grid`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var str = " Click <Hyperlink NavigateUri='https://www.google.com/'> here </Hyperlink> !!! ";
        grid.Children.Add(CreateTextBlock(str));
        grid.AddHandler(Hyperlink.RequestNavigateEvent, new RequestNavigateEventHandler(Hyperlink_RequestNavigate));
    }

    public TextBlock CreateTextBlock(string inlines)
    {
        var xaml = "<TextBlock xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">"
            + inlines + "</TextBlock>";
        return XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as TextBlock;
    }

    public void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri) { UseShellExecute = true });
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you bro u saved me